# Creating Release Notes in a VS code extension (Opening md files in preview mode?)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a Visual Studio Code extension and I would like to have some sort of Release Notes open up when the user uses a command.

I wrote the markdown file I would like to show

```js
export const activate = (context: vscode.ExtensionContext) => {
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('my.command', () => {
        let uri = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'RELEASE_NOTES.md'))
        vscode.window.showTextDocument(uri, {
            viewColumn: 1,
            preview: true
        });
    })
}
```

This opens up the .md file but I would like to have the formatted md file being shown.

How do I do this in vscode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `markdown.showPreview` from VS Code's built-in markdown extension to open a normal md preview of the file:

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('my.command', () => {
    let uri = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'RELEASE_NOTES.md'))
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('markdown.showPreview', uri)
})
```

Alternatively, use the same extension's `markdown.api.render` command to pass in a string of md content and get back html that you can use in your own extension's [webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview)